# Volume Randomly Goes to Maximum with Bluetooth Headset

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, siri

I have tried using two different bluetooth headsets with my iphone 6 and when using the headset and hitting the "call" button on the iphone, the volume will sometimes go to maximum level.

Basically I push the "call" button on the bluetooth headset and sometimes the "beep" noise that brings up Siri is extremely loud. To remedy the issue, I have to turn down the volume on the bluetooth headset, but when I do this it shows the volume as minimum on the iphone. For some reason this actually does bring down the volume, but is only temporary. Randomly it will get set back to maximum.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Restart your iphone once and then again connect with your bluetooth headset and give it a try..

Comment: @vembutech, I've tried that several times. This situation has been happening since I got the phone.

Comment: Since you got the phone.. ??? Then, take it to your nearest apple care or if you have warranty make a replacement...

Comment: This happens with all of the iphones and headsets I've used

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more details and possibly screenshots. Is the **Ringer** on maximum loudness or the **'Volume'** on maximum loudness? It would make sense if the headphones respond differently to the 'call' feature than to media, just like the iPhone itself does.

I don't know, it's just a guess based on the little information that you provided.

[image]
[image]

Please indicate which of these you are mentioning, if not both.

Comment: I am indicating volume is on maximum loudness (so I guess the right one). Even though the volume bar doesn't show it is set to maximum, the volume will be at maximum sometimes. I have to press the volume down button to bring down the volume. Sometimes it will even show on the volume bar that the volume is already at min, but the volume will decrease when I press the volume down button on my headset.